# Plussing numbers to a variable in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a rather simple question that I believe I can find a simple solution on, on this forum. My code goes here:

```
<?php
    $tekst = $_POST['tekst'];
    $billeder = $_POST['billeder'];
    $kørende = $_POST['kørende'];
    $cms = $_POST['cms'];
    $funktioner = $_POST['funktioner'];
    $select = $_POST['select'];
    $pris = 0;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($select >= 1) {
            $pris + 100;
        }
        if ($select >= 2) {
            $pris + 100;
        }
        echo $pris;
    }
    ?>
```

So if the user chooses "1" on a dropdown checkbox menu, the variable "$pris" will be 100. If the user chooses "2" on a dropdown checkbox menu, the variable "$pris" will be 200. Since it goes through both of them.
However, the "$pris" returns nothing right now due to the reason that it hasn't been set correctly. But are there a nice way doing this that I am not aware of? In such case, please let me know.

My new updated code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($select >= 1) {
            $pris = $pris + 100;
        }
        if ($select >= 2) {
            $pris = $pris + 100;
        }
        echo $pris;
    }
    ?>
```

However, I am wondering what you mean by using "+=". Can you explain?

Update:

I just got answered everything, thanks a lot, I will now proceed my work. :-)

Comment: you should do it `$pris = $pris + 100;`

Comment: imagine someone want to work after you on your code and have no specials chars like `ø`

Comment: Oh god, I wasn't even aware of that! Thanks for letting me know, I am always trying to keep those characters out of my code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Mp2WJ2Yd

Comment: @Peterrr Your updated IF is factually correct but logically wrong. In case $select = 2 then both the IF statements are being executed, however it gives you correct result because the remedy has been built that way. if select = 1 we should add 100, if select =2 we should add 200.

Answer (score 6):

`$pris + 100`  means nothing if you don't assign it somewhere.
Use **`+=`** or `$pris = $pris + 100;`

```
<?php
    $tekst = $_POST['tekst'];
    $billeder = $_POST['billeder'];
    $kørende = $_POST['kørende'];
    $cms = $_POST['cms'];
    $funktioner = $_POST['funktioner'];
    $select = $_POST['select'];
    $pris = 0;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($select == 1) {
            $pris += 100;
        }
        if ($select == 2) {
            $pris += 200;
        }
        echo $pris;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Not sure, the answer is valid. +1.

Comment: @HankyPanky it's someone's butthurt as you was faster

Answer (score 0):

You might want to move your echo outside the `if`, may be that is why nothing is printed out.

```
$pris = 0;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($select == 1) {
        $pris += 100;
    }
    else if ($select == 2) {
        $pris += 100;
    }

    //echo here will output nothing here if $_POST["submit"] is not set
}

echo $pris;  //this should output 0 if any condition above was not met
```